# Adding bytestrings with islice together in python

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm making a domain specific function based on more-itertools split_into() which fails on the last yield statement

```
from itertools import islice
def split_into(iterable_seq, sizes):
    """
    sizes = [5]+ it.repeat(32)
    iterable_seq = b'ACAACACACCAACCCAAACACAC'
    """
    iterate = iter(iterable_seq)
    for size in sizes:
        yield b'A'*(32-size)+islice(iterate, size)
```

Is there a way to add the output of islice to the bytestrings?

Here is another way that don't work:

```
yield b'A'*(32-size)+ b''.join(islice(iterate, size))
```

What is the difference between bytestrings of the format b'ACA' and the iterable of numbers that islice wants to put out e.g. [65, 67, 65]?  It seems there shouldn't be any need for coercing the number form back to its original string form.

Answer (score 1):

The `bytes` function appears to be what you're looking for:

```py
yield b'A'*(32-size)+bytes(islice(iterate, size))
```